# SQL Server CASE expression in WHERE clause to check NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to execute this query in SQL Server:

```
select * from users where case when 1=1 then name is null else true end;
```

But I got this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'

This query works in MySQL successfully. Can you please tell me the equivalent of this query in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the logic behind your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do such expression, syntax is wrong.

If you want to *choose* the condition, you have to play with logical operators:

```
where (1=1 and name is null)
   or (1<>1 and 1=1)
```

I replaced `true` with condition that always evalutes to true (`1=1`), because `true` itself is another synta error in your query.

Comment: It works but I don't know why case statement does not work :(

Comment: @Nico you need to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), on SQL Server its a *CASE EXPRESSION* not a *CASE STATEMENT* meaning that the result of the *case expression* is a value not a condition.